# Android execute HTTPGet not working in this line

Tags: android, http-get

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://app2.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution/psi/psi-readings-over-the-last-24-hours");
    HttpResponse response;

    response = client.execute(get);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WAD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line+"\n");
    }
    in.close();
    charset = sb.toString();
    tv.setText(charset);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this line,

> response = client.execute(get);

The program doesn't seem to continue the code, it just hangs there and does nothing.

I have declared permissions for internet, but I can't find what's wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have any exceptions on your LogCat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you haven't mentioned anything about it and it isn't clear from your question, you may be performing network operations in main application thread.

This will cause a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) if you're testing on Android 3.0 or later, but will make the user interface "hang"/"freeze" on earlier versions. To avoid this, always perform all your network operations on a non-UI thread, for example an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: "It seems you are performing network operations in main Thread" - Not really. Nothing in the question suggests that. On Android 3.0+, the application would crash if he were performing network operations in the main thread - that's not mentioned in the question. On earlier versions it would work.

Comment: You are right, I am calling the method in the mainthread. I shall look into the solution!

Comment: @user2519193 you are welcome, and also welcome to the stackoverflow. If you think the answer was helpful you can upvote/accept the answer :)

Comment: @StinePike Thanks for the answer, I added this line
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

and now it works!

Comment: I've edited your answer, as it was simply incorrect. Also added information about why it's doing what it's doing.

Comment: @MichellBak thanks ..but why it was incorrect.. I clearly wrote that from which sdk version it was the problem .. anyway thanks again

Comment: @StinePike You wrote "It seems you are performing network operations in main Thread". Nothing in the question points to him performing network operations in the main thread. He doesn't mention an Android version and he doesn't mention if he's using a separate thread for it.

The answer itself isn't incorrect, but your first paragraph was. I also expanded on your answer with a more detailed description.

Comment: may be you havent seen my edited answer just after your first comment I pointed the honeycomb ... and from personal performance i was pretty sure that it was this problem :D.. anyway I am not very good at writing answers in proper language.. thanks for the help :)